# How to make the last div receive y overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say my html is setup like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="site_banner">
            <img>
        </div>
        <div id="site_content">
            <div id="home_menu"></div>
            <div id="home_content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

All I want is my home_content to fill the rest of the view and then any additional content in home_content to be in overflow instead of overflow being in html, so that the site_banner and home_menu are always on screen as the user scrolls down and never disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're saying it sounds like you should be putting the "site banner" and "home menu" in a header tag which means it should be structured like this.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <div id="site_banner"><img></div>
       <div id="home_menu"></div>
   </header>

   <div id="site_content">
        <div id="home_content"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

here's a fiddle of it https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/rx2qn1h9/

Here's the CSS I added to make it stay put

```
header{
position:fixed;  /*this makes it stay in place*/
display:block;
top:0px;         /*this bumps it to the very top of the page*/
width:100%;
height:80px;
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#site_content").height($(window).height()-$("#site_banner").height());
$("#home_content").css("overflow-y","auto").height($("#site_content").height()-$("#home_menu").height());
```

Here's a JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/h1bcn5p0/

Comment: Do you know of a pure css way of doing this or is this something that requires jQuery?

Comment: I guess none, unless you specify the height of your #site_banner and #home_menu.